# Putting Logger.info in static block

Tags: java, log4j

I have the following class

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    static
    {
        logger.info("some text");
    }
}
```

Is it safe to assume that by the time we reach `logger.info`, the log4j system is initialized and is ready to emit logs?

It seems that if I am able to do a `Logger.getLogger()` and get back a valid Logger instance, it means that Log4j is initialized, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is. Static initializers (that is, both `static {}` blocks and initial assignments to static variables) are executed in the order they are declared.

Default initialization of log4j relies on a static block in a log4j class `LogManager` that is executed once `Logger` class is loaded, and it is loaded prior to its first use. This is why your construction works.

Comment: It seems that when using SLF4j, it is not guaranteed that log4j is also ready.

Comment: @Timo No, it's not, at least not with slf4j-api package alone. You need a package with a StaticLoggerBinder class; for example slf4j-log4j12.

Comment: And if you have slf4j-log4j12 on the classpath, is it guaranteed then?

Comment: In my case I also wanted to log something in the static initializer, however it does not log. I assume that this is because my whole application code is in a JAR starting with "a", whereas log4j is loaded later...

Answer (score 0):

See this part of the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4). It talks about what happens when you initialise a class. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7) part talks about static initialisers. In answer to your question then AFAIK the static blocks are executed in the order they occur. They will be executed when the class is loaded which can happen when you create an instance of it or access a static var/method of it.